# graph theory - connect point in 3D space with other three nearest points (distance based)

Tags: python, python-3.x, graph-theory, chemistry, rdkit

I want to connect nodes (Atoms) with the three nearest nodes(atoms).

I am doing

```
ad1 = np.zeros((31,31))
for i in range(31):
    dist_i = dist_mat[i]
    cut_off = sorted(dist_i)[3]
    ad1[i, np.where((dist_i<=cut_off) & (dist_i!=0.0))] = 1

np.sum(ad1, axis=1) #[3,3,3,3........3]

np.sum(ad1, axis=0)
#array([3., 3., 2., 2., 2., 4., 2., 5., 2., 3., 2., 3., 3., 2., 3., 6., 3.,
   5., 3., 4., 2., 3., 2., 4., 3., 3., 2., 4., 3., 2., 3.])
```

I want `np.sum(ad1, axis=0)` to be all 3. That would mean all node (atoms) are connected to exactly 3 nearest nodes. As we can see node/atom 5 is connected to 4 other nodes/atoms which is wrong, I want it to be connected to exactly 3 nearest nodes. How do I do it.

Below is the distance matrix of 31 atoms (31 X 31).

```
0.0000,6.8223,7.5588,4.8966,7.2452,2.7778,3.7082,2.7345,7.1540,6.8273,3.6995,7.4136,4.6132,5.8456,2.8037,5.4881,8.1769,2.7361,8.3034,4.9450,4.8225,4.6152,4.8243,9.4876,7.2391,2.9941,7.4180,5.8523,7.6310,5.5996,8.1761
6.8223,0.0000,3.0097,2.8567,2.6647,5.0092,5.8451,6.8037,6.7031,4.8983,7.5806,5.2873,5.5000,7.0038,4.9530,3.9763,7.0263,4.8941,4.7416,6.8450,2.8166,2.9221,5.5502,7.0328,5.5148,7.6318,2.7456,5.1150,2.9654,4.2863,5.3168
7.5588,3.0097,0.0000,2.8679,2.9242,5.1443,6.8372,6.5621,5.5169,3.0135,6.8412,4.6886,4.2507,5.4276,5.8673,4.8804,4.7149,6.5707,2.5568,6.3820,5.0625,4.2533,5.0600,5.2125,2.9262,7.8126,4.6864,5.4224,2.6001,3.2330,4.7116
4.8966,2.8567,2.8679,0.0000,3.8064,3.0221,5.1335,4.1131,5.8284,2.8610,5.1354,3.8488,2.8086,4.9618,3.0028,2.7539,5.7401,4.1214,4.5830,5.4268,2.9346,2.8122,2.9319,6.8084,3.8015,5.8992,3.8516,4.9611,2.9212,3.0441,5.7392
7.2452,2.6647,2.9242,3.8064,0.0000,4.7907,5.1676,7.2899,4.5138,5.5206,7.0249,6.9978,5.3888,5.7435,6.2424,6.0645,5.2615,5.6079,2.8907,5.3589,4.7384,2.8152,6.6866,4.6140,4.7660,6.9472,5.3921,3.2734,4.7050,2.9157,2.6684
2.7778,5.0092,5.1443,3.0221,4.7907,0.0000,2.8352,3.0025,4.6425,5.0210,2.8371,6.4170,2.6958,3.6516,3.1115,4.9489,5.5823,3.0042,5.5496,3.0193,4.1730,2.6916,4.1796,6.7613,4.7913,2.8772,6.4156,3.6500,5.9378,2.8228,5.5754
3.7082,5.8451,6.8372,5.1335,5.1676,2.8352,0.0000,5.4535,5.0179,7.5889,4.7500,8.8240,5.4549,5.4488,4.9281,6.8616,7.0789,2.8247,6.7504,3.1734,4.9441,2.9387,6.8368,7.3498,7.0263,2.7571,7.6165,2.7391,7.8184,4.2915,5.4352
2.7345,6.8037,6.5621,4.1131,7.2899,3.0025,5.4535,0.0000,6.9646,4.8923,2.8238,5.6867,2.8002,4.7436,2.7895,4.7319,7.0025,4.5800,7.4954,5.2983,5.3961,5.3071,2.7803,8.9227,5.5914,4.2758,7.1749,6.6267,6.5470,5.1104,8.2905
7.1540,6.7031,5.5169,5.8284,4.5138,4.6425,5.0179,6.9646,0.0000,6.7047,5.0056,9.1250,4.9769,2.9634,7.5819,8.5546,2.8061,6.9800,3.6751,2.5834,7.6541,4.9881,7.6494,2.7948,4.5088,5.2110,9.1264,2.9761,7.8062,2.7941,2.8038
6.8273,4.8983,3.0135,2.8610,5.5206,5.0210,7.5889,4.8923,6.7047,0.0000,5.8617,2.7465,2.9301,5.1272,4.9558,3.9808,5.3162,6.8165,4.7404,6.8576,5.5561,5.5098,2.8152,7.0330,2.6644,7.6461,5.2912,7.0096,2.9674,4.2945,7.0258
3.6995,7.5806,6.8412,5.1354,7.0249,2.8371,4.7500,2.8238,5.0056,5.8617,0.0000,7.6266,2.9474,2.7359,4.9270,6.8677,5.4363,5.4517,6.7478,3.1721,6.8329,5.4529,4.9555,7.3438,5.1708,2.7597,8.8287,5.4452,7.8249,4.2909,7.0646
7.4136,5.2873,4.6886,3.8488,6.9978,6.4170,8.8240,5.6867,9.1250,2.7465,7.6266,0.0000,4.9529,7.5866,4.8602,2.7541,8.0299,7.1729,7.0207,8.9107,5.2910,6.5588,2.9146,9.5249,5.3922,9.1160,4.1719,8.7725,2.7497,6.4529,9.0793
4.6132,5.5000,4.2507,2.8086,5.3888,2.6958,5.4549,2.8002,4.9769,2.9301,2.9474,4.9529,0.0000,2.8097,3.9433,4.7505,4.4056,5.3122,4.8719,4.3293,5.3691,4.4387,2.8442,6.4077,2.8070,4.8696,6.5606,5.3482,5.0545,2.9281,6.2031
5.8456,7.0038,5.4276,4.9618,5.7435,3.6516,5.4488,4.7436,2.9634,5.1272,2.7359,7.5866,2.8097,0.0000,6.2398,7.3805,2.7234,6.6316,4.5653,2.8038,7.3250,5.3513,5.6427,4.8167,3.2793,4.4545,8.7753,4.6687,7.1729,2.8747,5.2395
2.8037,4.9530,5.8673,3.0028,6.2424,3.1115,4.9281,2.7895,7.5819,4.9558,4.9270,4.8602,3.9433,6.2398,0.0000,2.6964,7.9654,2.7924,7.3935,6.1211,2.8429,3.9452,2.8424,9.2720,6.2355,5.1988,4.8668,6.2430,5.2004,5.1737,7.9659
5.4881,3.9763,4.8804,2.7539,6.0645,4.9489,6.8616,4.7319,8.5546,3.9808,6.8677,2.7541,4.7505,7.3805,2.6964,0.0000,8.3401,4.7306,7.1148,7.8221,2.7718,4.7476,2.7753,9.5030,6.0617,7.5711,2.7577,7.3777,3.1397,5.7882,8.3392
8.1769,7.0263,4.7149,5.7401,5.2615,5.5823,7.0789,7.0025,2.8061,5.3162,5.4363,8.0299,4.4056,2.7234,7.9654,8.3401,0.0000,8.3066,2.9172,4.5762,8.3187,6.2166,6.9974,2.6988,2.6667,6.8504,9.0816,5.2518,7.0366,3.3010,4.3079
2.7361,4.8941,6.5707,4.1214,5.6079,3.0042,2.8247,4.5800,6.9800,6.8165,5.4517,7.1729,5.3122,6.6316,2.7924,4.7306,8.3066,0.0000,7.5094,5.3015,2.7788,2.8080,5.4012,8.9373,7.2956,4.2691,5.6901,4.7565,6.5515,5.1204,7.0169
8.3034,4.7416,2.5568,4.5830,2.8907,5.5496,6.7504,7.4954,3.6751,4.7404,6.7478,7.0207,4.8719,4.5653,7.3935,7.1148,2.9172,7.5094,0.0000,5.4477,6.7736,4.8812,6.7675,2.6661,2.8871,7.5857,7.0211,4.5660,5.1569,2.7695,2.9165
4.9450,6.8450,6.3820,5.4268,5.3589,3.0193,3.1734,5.2983,2.5834,6.8576,3.1721,8.9107,4.3293,2.8038,6.1211,7.8221,4.5762,5.3015,5.4477,0.0000,6.7806,4.3263,6.7865,5.3395,5.3642,2.6393,8.9072,2.7997,8.0722,3.1518,4.5623
4.8225,2.8166,5.0625,2.9346,4.7384,4.1730,4.9441,5.3961,7.6541,5.5561,6.8329,5.2910,5.3691,7.3250,2.8429,2.7718,8.3187,2.7788,6.7736,6.7806,0.0000,2.8411,4.6768,8.8466,6.6849,6.5259,2.9190,5.6409,4.2802,5.1556,7.0036
4.6152,2.9221,4.2533,2.8122,2.8152,2.6916,2.9387,5.3071,4.9881,5.5098,5.4529,6.5588,4.4387,5.3513,3.9452,4.7476,6.2166,2.8080,4.8812,4.3263,2.8411,0.0000,5.3713,6.4170,5.3921,4.8619,4.9490,2.8105,5.0539,2.9321,4.4129
4.8243,5.5502,5.0600,2.9319,6.6866,4.1796,6.8368,2.7803,7.6494,2.8152,4.9555,2.9146,2.8442,5.6427,2.8424,2.7753,6.9974,5.4012,6.7675,6.7865,4.6768,5.3713,0.0000,8.8413,4.7294,6.5361,5.2956,7.3262,4.2788,5.1556,8.3129
9.4876,7.0328,5.2125,6.8084,4.6140,6.7613,7.3498,8.9227,2.7948,7.0330,7.3438,9.5249,6.4077,4.8167,9.2720,9.5030,2.6988,8.9373,2.6661,5.3395,8.8466,6.4170,8.8413,0.0000,4.6127,7.9200,9.5247,4.8201,7.8081,4.1075,2.6956
7.2391,5.5148,2.9262,3.8015,4.7660,4.7913,7.0263,5.5914,4.5088,2.6644,5.1708,5.3922,2.8070,3.2793,6.2355,6.0617,2.6667,7.2956,2.8871,5.3642,6.6849,5.3921,4.7294,4.6127,0.0000,6.9513,6.9963,5.7431,4.7049,2.9171,5.2546
2.9941,7.6318,7.8126,5.8992,6.9472,2.8772,2.7571,4.2758,5.2110,7.6461,2.7597,9.1160,4.8696,4.4545,5.1988,7.5711,6.8504,4.2691,7.5857,2.6393,6.5259,4.8619,6.5361,7.9200,6.9513,0.0000,9.1125,4.4513,8.8145,4.8939,6.8395
7.4180,2.7456,4.6864,3.8516,5.3921,6.4156,7.6165,7.1749,9.1264,5.2912,8.8287,4.1719,6.5606,8.7753,4.8668,2.7577,9.0816,5.6901,7.0211,8.9072,2.9190,4.9490,5.2956,9.5247,6.9963,9.1125,0.0000,7.5797,2.7482,6.4514,8.0302
5.8523,5.1150,5.4224,4.9611,3.2734,3.6500,2.7391,6.6267,2.9761,7.0096,5.4452,8.7725,5.3482,4.6687,6.2430,7.3777,5.2518,4.7565,4.5660,2.7997,5.6409,2.8105,7.3262,4.8201,5.7431,4.4513,7.5797,0.0000,7.1676,2.8724,2.7190
7.6310,2.9654,2.6001,2.9212,4.7050,5.9378,7.8184,6.5470,7.8062,2.9674,7.8249,2.7497,5.0545,7.1729,5.2004,3.1397,7.0366,6.5515,5.1569,8.0722,4.2802,5.0539,4.2788,7.8081,4.7049,8.8145,2.7482,7.1676,0.0000,5.1559,7.0354
5.5996,4.2863,3.2330,3.0441,2.9157,2.8228,4.2915,5.1104,2.7941,4.2945,4.2909,6.4529,2.9281,2.8747,5.1737,5.7882,3.3010,5.1204,2.7695,3.1518,5.1556,2.9321,5.1556,4.1075,2.9171,4.8939,6.4514,2.8724,5.1559,0.0000,3.2927
8.1761,5.3168,4.7116,5.7392,2.6684,5.5754,5.4352,8.2905,2.8038,7.0258,7.0646,9.0793,6.2031,5.2395,7.9659,8.3392,4.3079,7.0169,2.9165,4.5623,7.0036,4.4129,8.3129,2.6956,5.2546,6.8395,8.0302,2.7190,7.0354,3.2927,0.0000
```

**Edit 1**

Thank-you, @yatu, and @mathfux but Kdtree does not produce what I want.

so from @mathfux answer if the nearest list of 3 is 0,1,2 and 0 has the nearest list of 1,4,2 then the algorithm should give more importance to distances and break the connections of 3 and 0. 3 should find other points nearest to it, instead of joining with 0. if 3 cannot find other points nearest to it then 0 has to exclude either 1 or 2 based on the distance and include 3 because 3 could not find 3 nearest points other than 0,1,2.

Also one can see 0 is connected to 25 but 25 is not connected to 0 which is wrong. if 0 is connected to 25 then 25 should also be connected to 0.

```
[ 0, 17,  7, 25]
[ 5, 21, 12,  6]
[ 6, 25, 27, 17]
[10, 25, 13,  7]
[12,  5,  3, 24]
[21,  5,  3,  4]
[25,  6, 10, 19]
[29,  4, 12, 24]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that such connection might not always be possible because you are not able to hold your matrix symmetric. Actually, matrix of distance is not needed for explanation.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
points = np.array([[0,0],[0,1],[0,-1],[1,0],[-0.5,0]])
plt.scatter(*np.transpose(points))
for i in range(len(points)):
    plt.text(points[i][0], points[i][1], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4][i], fontsize=24)
```

[image]

If you, let's say, find 3 closest points `0`, `1`, `2` for point `3` this doesn't mean that 3 is in a list of closest points of 0.

If you still want to find 3 closests points, you don't need that looping at all, just use `np.argsort(dist_mat, axis=1)[:,1:4]` to find indexes of closest points or `np.sort(dist_mat, axis=1)[:,1:4]` to find distances. In case you need to work with points instead of `dist_max` (which is an overhead), `KDTree` is a better option.

Comment: right, so either 3 should find some other points, or 0 should exclude 1 or 2 based on distance and it should have 3 in the list. 0 = (3, 4, 1) bcoz 3 does not have any other nearest 3 = (1,0,2) hence 0 is commited now it cannot exclude 3 any more.

Answer (score 3):

A [`KDTree`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KDTree.html) would be more appropriate for what you're trying to do. Once you've built the tree, you can search for the `3` nearest points to all points in the tree:

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KDTree

tree = KDTree(X, leaf_size=2)
dist, ind = tree.query(X, k=3)
```

To check the result, we can verify that the three smallest values in the first row, match the three smallest distances returned by the `query` indexing on the first row `ind[0]`:

```
np.sort(X[0])[:3]
#array([0.    , 2.7345, 2.7361])

X[0,ind[0]]
# array([0.    , 2.7361, 2.7345])
```

Comment: Also one can see 0 is connected to 25 but 25 is not connected to 0 which is wrong. if 0 is connected to 25 then 25 should also be connected to 0. see my edited question